# form element added with jquery not performing correct action

Tags: jquery, html, forms, action

I've got a form (#waldform) that I want to appear only after a  previous form (#modelform) is submitted. Both #modelform and #waldform call python functions. If I include #waldform directly into the html file, everything works fine and the python function is called. However, if I make it appear only after #modelform is submitted, using jquery, like in my code below, the python function isn't called and the site url changes to # at the end.

Here is the jquery. The form element is added in the first function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    //call estimate python function
    $(function() {

        $("#modelform").submit(function() {

            // post the form values via AJAX...
            $.post('/estimate', {name: $("#mymodel").val()}, function(data) {

                var $a_var = data['title']
                var $element = $('<div class="item">' + $a_var + '</div><br>');

                $('body').append($element) ;

                //FORM ADDED HERE
                $('body').append('<form id="waldform" action="#" method="post"><input type="text" id="waldnum" /><input type="submit" value="Wald Test" /></form>');


            });

        return false ;
        });
    });



    //call wald python function
    $(function() {

        $("#waldform").submit(function() {

            //post the form values via AJAX...
            $.post('/wald', {name: $("#waldnum").val()}, function(data) {

                var $a_var = data['title']
                var $element = $('<div class="item">' + $a_var + '</div><br>');

                $('body').append($element) ;

            });

        return false ;
        });
    });



});
```

Here is the html if needed. If I include #waldform directly into this html code then the python function is called correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head> 

                <script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="static/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js"></script>
                <script type='text/javascript' src='static/js_test.js'></script>
                <script type='text/javascript' src='static/jquery.form.js'></script> 

                <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>

            <form id="dataform" action="submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="file" name="myfile" id="myFile"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit File"/>
            </form>

            <form id="modelform" action="#" method="post">
                <input type="text" id="mymodel" />
                <input type="submit" value="Estimate" />
            </form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Both instances of `$(function() {})` in your code are redundant.

Comment: thanks!!! still learning jquery :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding to the submit event of the 2nd form before the 2nd form exists. Move it to after you add it.

```
//FORM ADDED HERE
$('body').append('<form id="waldform" action="#" method="post"><input type="text" id="waldnum" /><input type="submit" value="Wald Test" /></form>');

//BIND EVENT HERE
$("#waldform").submit(function() {
```

Comment: Thanks for responding quickly. I'm not quite sure what you mean. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Basically, when you do `$("#waldform")`, it only selects elements that exist at that point in time. Future elements will not be affected by it. updated answer slightly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate it using .on()

```
$(document).on('submit', '#waldform', function(e) {
    alert('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```